# Find the cartesian equation for $(e^t,t^2)$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

This isn't one I recognise. I want to express it as $f(e^t,t^2)=c$ (a level curve) but I'm not sure how.

I have arrived at a partial derivative equation (knowing that in the direction $(e^t,t^2)$ that the directional derivative of $f$ should be zero) but this seems 1) overkill 2) difficult given this is early in a book on differential geometry.

The examples in the book are ones that are not far from recognisable shapes (like the circle, or asteroid).

I'm stuck, which is embarrassing.

Comment: $\log(x)^2-y=0$?

Comment: Just about to add common sense kicked in $y=t^2=\ln(e^t)^2$ @AmitaiYuval I'm being really silly today!

Answer (score 1):

If you call $x=e^t$, with $x>0$, then $t=\log x$. Thus, the second coordinate is $y=t^2=(\log x)^2$. So the points in the curve are $(x,(\log x)^2)$, with $x>0$.

If you want to write it as an equation, you may write $f(x,y)=0$, with $f(x,y)=y-(\log x)^2$, or $f(x,y)=x-e^{\sqrt y}$. In both cases you are limited to $x>0$, $y\geq0$.

Comment: Fine, but I think $y$ may be zero also

Comment: Good point, thanks.